# Are these two versions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Rudin - PMA p.162
>
> Let $(X\tau)$ be a compact Hausdorff space.
>
> Let $d$ be the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $\rho$ be the sup metric on $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.
>
> If $\mathscr{A}$ separates points and vanished nowhere, then $\mathscr{A}$ is dense in $(C(X,\mathbb{R}),\rho)$.

Another is:

> Wikipedia
>
> If $\mathscr{A}$ separates points and contains a non-zero constant function, then $\mathscr{A}$ is dense in $(C(X,\mathbb{R}),\rho)$.

It's trivial that the theorem in Rudin's text implies that in Wikipedia.

However, I'm not sure the theorem in Wikipedia implies that in Rudin's text.

To sum up, if $\mathscr{A}$ separates points and vanish nowhere, does $\mathscr{A}$ contain a nonzero constant function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the implication is false. Let $X = [0,1]$ and consider the algebra $A$ of all functions of the form $(1 + x)f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial.

This algebra satisfies Rudin's condition, but not Wikipedia's.